# $x_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(1/(\sqrt{1} + \sqrt{3}) + 1/(\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5}) + \cdots + 1/(\sqrt{2n-1} + \sqrt{2n+1}))$. Find $N(\epsilon)$ by definition

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, epsilon-delta

Firstly, it is not that hard to notice that $1/(\sqrt{1} + \sqrt{3}) + 1/(\sqrt{3} + \sqrt{5}) + \cdots + 1/(\sqrt{2n-1} + \sqrt{2n+1}) = \frac{\sqrt{2n+1}- 1}{2\sqrt{n}}$

Hence, it is pretty easy to claculate limit, it is $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$.

But what I am looking for is finding interdependence between $N$ and $\epsilon$ from definition:

$$\forall \epsilon>0\;\;\exists N \in \mathbb{N}:\;\forall n \geq N \implies \left|x_n - \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right|<\epsilon$$

As an example, for sequence $y_n=\frac{1}{n}$, $N(\epsilon) = \lceil1/\epsilon\rceil$. So, for any positive $\epsilon$ we basically find interdependence such that we can find $N$ very quick.

But in my problem I struggle with finding such $N(\epsilon)$.
All hints and solutions will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start:

$$\begin{align}\left|x_n-\frac {\sqrt2}2\right|&=\left|\frac{\sqrt{2n+1}-1}{2\sqrt n}-\frac {\sqrt2}2\right|\\
&=\frac1{2\sqrt n}\left|\sqrt{2n+1}-1-\sqrt{2n}\right|\\
&=\frac1{2\sqrt n}\left|\frac 1{\sqrt{2n+1}+\sqrt{2n}}-1\right|\\
&=\frac1{2\sqrt n}\left(1-\frac 1{\sqrt{2n+1}+\sqrt{2n}}\right)\\
&<\frac1{2\sqrt n}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you! Didn’t try such approach

Comment: Wait, I have just tried to do it and I am not sure that your 2nd transition is correct

Comment: Are you referring to $$\sqrt{2n+1}-\sqrt{2n} = \frac {(\sqrt{2n+1}-\sqrt{2n})(\sqrt{2n+1}+\sqrt{2n})}{\sqrt{2n+1}+\sqrt{2n}}= \frac {2n+1-2n}{\sqrt{2n+1}+\sqrt{2n}}$$

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, you are right. Thank you